# ggplot2 scale_x_log10() destroys/doesn't apply for function plotted via stat_function()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I finally managed to plot my custom fitted function over my data in ggplot2 but when I log-transform the x axis the plotted function gets totally messed up.
It looks like the `scale_x_log10()` applies only to the plotted data but not to the function.

How can I make the function to appear in the correct scale?

Here is an modified example from Hadley's stat_function() documentation:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
qplot(x, geom="density") + stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour="red")
```

and now with log10 x-axis:

```
qplot(x, geom="density") + stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour="red") + scale_x_log10()
```

---

### update

Okay, I think my example was not very helpful so I try it differently:

essentially what I want is to reproduce a plot I did with curve(). I fitted a Hill function to my data and now want to plot it:

```
# the function
HillFunction <- function(ec50,hill,rmax,x) {rmax/(1+(ec50/x)^hill)} 
# fitted parameters
hill.args <- list(ec50=10^-2, hill=.7, rmax=1)                     

curve(HillFunction(ec50=hill.args$ec50,rmax=hill.args$rmax, hill=hill.args$hill,x),from=10^-5, to=10^5,log="x")
```

so curve() gives me a smooth sigmoidal curve as expected. Now I try to reproduce the same plot with ggplot:

I add some data from 10^-5 to 10^5 just to define the plotting range, not sure if there are better ways

```
p <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=c(10^-5:10^5)), aes(x=x))  + stat_function(fun=HillFunction, args=hill.args, n=3000, color="red")
```

now if I plot `p` everything looks fine, like the `curve()` plot without the logscale:

```
p
curve(HillFunction(ec50=hill.args$ec50,rmax=hill.args$rmax, hill=hill.args$hill,x),from=10^-5, to=10^5)
```

If I transform the coordinate system I get a sigmoidal curve but not smooth at all and the curve looks way to steep, but maybe that comes from x-scaling:

p + coord_trans(x="log10")

And if I define the x scale to be a log-scale the plot looks smooth but stops at 10^0:

```
p + scale_x_log10()
```

and I get the following warning: `Removed 1500 rows containing missing values (geom_path).`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Does it look like you expect if you pass `limits = c(0.001,1000)` to `scale_x_log10`?

Comment: ggplot2 is silently throwing away all values of `x` and `dnorm(x)` that are less than 0 (because log10(-1) = NaN).

Comment: Perhaps you wanted a logarithmic axis on the vertical scale, `scale_y_log10()`, rather than on the horizontal one? (This is often used to highlight the differences between a gaussian density and densities with fatter tails.)

Answer (score 5):

### Proposed Solution

The following code is one way to get ggplot2 to do what I think you are trying to accomplish.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Define function. Fitted parameters included as default values.
HillFunction = function(x, ec50=0.01, hill=0.7, rmax=1.0) {
    result = rmax / (1 + (ec50 / x)^hill)
    return(result)
} 

# Create x such that points are evenly spread in log space.
x = 10^seq(-5, 5, 0.2) 
y_fit = HillFunction(x)
y_raw = y_fit + rnorm(length(y_fit), sd=0.05)

dat = data.frame(x, y_fit, y_raw)

plot_1 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y_raw)) +
         geom_point() +
         geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y_fit), colour="red") +
         scale_x_log10() +
         opts(title="Figure 1. Proposed workaround.")

png("plot_1.png", height=450, width=450)
print(plot_1)
dev.off()
```

[image: Figure 1]

### Problems With stat_function()

1. `stat_function()` is trying to evaluate `HillFunction()` for
   negative values of `x`. This why you get the `missing values` error.
2. stat_function() is not evaluating `HillFunction()` for any `x`
       values between 0 and 1. It is selecting `x` in linear space,
       ignoring that `scale_x_log10()` has been specified.

The following code illustrates the problem, but I still can't explain why `stat_function()` diverges so much from `y_fit` in Figure 2.

```
plot_2 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y_fit)) +
         geom_point() +
         stat_function(fun=HillFunction, colour="red") +
         scale_x_log10() +
         opts(title="Figure 2. stat_function() misbehaving?")

png("plot_2.png", height=450, width=450)
print(plot_2)
dev.off()


png("plot_3.png", height=450, width=450)

plot(x, y_fit, pch=20, log="x")
curve(HillFunction, col="red", add=TRUE)
title("Figure 3. curve() behaving as expected.")

dev.off()
```

[image: Figure 2]

[image]

Comment: Thank you I think that workaround helps me a lot. I hope there will be a fix for stat_function() at some point.

Answer (score 3):

bdemarest shows the problem; the function is computed with the transformed (not original) x values. A workaround is to create a function which undoes the transformation before computing. Using bdemarest data and functions:

```
HillFunction10 <- function(x) {
  HillFunction(10^x)
}

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y_fit)) +
         geom_point() +
         stat_function(fun=HillFunction10, colour="red") +
         scale_x_log10() +
         ggtitle("Figure 2. stat_function() misbehaving?")
```

[image]

I think this is an error and have filed a pull request on it: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1011