# Maintaining custom labels using scale_x_discrete and applying stat_function to a ggplot

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a custom function on a plot, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 20, 0.5), y = jitter(4.5*x, 20))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))
g + geom_point() + 
stat_function(fun = function(x) 4.5*x)
```

[image: Plot of y = 4.5*x]

But say I want to modify my x-axis labels like this:

```
g + geom_point() + 
scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1, 10, 20), labels = c("A little", "Moderate", "A lot")) +
stat_function(fun = function(x) 4.5*x)
```

I get the warning message below, and the plot fails to draw:

> Warning message: Computation failed in `stat_function()`: attempt to
>   apply non-function

How can I change the x-axis to my own custom labels and have my function display as well?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382032/ggplot2-scale-x-log10-destroys-doesnt-apply-for-function-plotted-via-stat-fun) but the answer seems very complex for something that seems quite simple!

Comment: How about using `scale_x_continuous` instead?

Comment: That works - why does it work!? I never even thought... ugh

Comment: My humble guess is that `scale_x_discrete` makes the `x` variable categorical (factor) and caused error somewhere.  I don't know why it results in "apply non-function" error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter suggested, you should use `scale_x_continuous`, e.g

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 4.5*x) + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 10, 20), 
          labels = c("A little", "Moderate", "A lot"))
```

When you use the `scale_x_discrete`, I'm guessing that `ggplot2` changes your data from numeric to a factor and `stat_function` must check for numerics - I'm basing this on the fact that change `4.5*x` to `4.5*as.numeric(x)` doesn't solve the problem.

However, `stat_smooth` still works with discrete scales - the `lowess` method is OK with factors.

Comment: thanks @csgillespie, and thanks again Kota Mori. I like using stat_function, because I can plot the curves of different models on my graph, not the "canned" ones ggplot provides (however useful they can be in other situations!).